# How to divide a Vector3 to recover a scale factor?

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, linear-algebra

I have object I'm scaling by setting its localScale to (1, 1, 1) multiplied by a float `size`.

```
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * size;
```

Now I need to get the size value back from the vector. How can I do that?

I tried to do this:

```
size = transform.localScale / Vector3(1, 1, 1)
```

But I get this error:

> Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun fact: there are only four possible [division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) over tuples of reals:

- [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) (1 dimensional)
- [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) (2 dimensional)
- [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) (4 dimensional)
- [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) (8 dimensional)

Any other division algebra must be isomorphic to one of these, by the Frobenius theorem.

Note that 3-vectors are not in the list! There is no complete and consistent way to define division over 3-dimensional vectors. In fact, William Rowan Hamilton was *looking* for a way to divide triples when he discovered quaternions.

So, vector division is not a useful way to think about this problem.

If your scale is only ever uniform, then you have the same value in all three components x, y, and z, so you can just pick one:

```
float size = transform.localScale.x;
```

If you can have non-uniform scale, then to digest three potentially different scale factors down into one, you need some way to average them, either taking their arithmetic mean:

```
float averageSize = (transform.localScale.x 
                   + transform.localScale.y
                   + transform.localScale.z) / 3f;
```

(If some might be negative, you'd want to take the absolute value of each component before adding them up)

Or their geometric mean:

```
float volumeScale = transform.localScale.x 
                  * transform.localScale.y
                  * transform.localScale.z;

float averageScale = Mathf.Pow(volumeScale, 1f/3f);
```

(This one works even with negatives, and the sign at the end tells you whether there's been a net reflection)

More generally, if you have some vector `V` that's been scaled by a scalar `a` to make a vector `S`, you can recover `a` from `S` like so:

```
float a = Vector3.Dot(S, V) / V.sqrMagnitude;
```

Why does this work? The dot product gives us the length of the two vectors times the cosine of the angle between them (cos 0° = 1), so that's `a ||v||²`. Dividing by the squared length of v gets us `a` again — including its sign (since cos 180° = -1).